# Fix and unfix a photo and content below cover photo on scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

Here's what I'd like to execute:

1. Fixed navigation
2. Photo spanning full width of the page (may also be deeper than browser window which is okay because I want the user to scroll past the image.

So I suppose the photo should be fixed. The part that's hard to create is that once the window reaches the point of half photo, half story below, the story below should begin to cover the photo (until the photo is no longer visible) and the page begin to scroll up.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiimmike/8UHbq/2/), and the code:

```
<body>

  <header> <span class="white">Home</span></header>
  <!--A FIXED HEADER ALWAYS IN SIGHT-->

  <div id="content">

    <section class="intro">
    <!--CONTAINER FOR PHOTO AND HEADLINE-->

      <h1 class="atop">Headline</h1>
      <img class="scrollimg" src="http://ww2.hdnux.com/photos/23/74/63/5229797/3/1200x706.jpg"/>

    </section>
    <!--SECTION SHOULD BE FIXED BUT ONCE SCROLLED 75% OF PHOTO, STORY CONTAINER BELOW SHOULD BEGIN TO COVER PHOTO-->

    <section class="story">
    <!--CONTAINER FOR STORY WITH WHITE BACKGROUND BEGINS TO COVER PHOTO UPON SCROLLING DOWN-->

      <div id="row">
    <!--DUMMY COPY-->

        <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

       <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

       <ol>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
          <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
       </ol>

       <blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

        <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

       <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

       <ol>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
          <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
       </ol>

       <blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

      </div>

    </section>

  </div>

<div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
```

with what I thought was some helpful code from [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YK72r/2/).

The fiddle seems to perform a similar trick in that the footer pushes content up upon reaching a set position upon scrolling.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this is being downvoted.

Comment: @RustyToms, I gave a counterbalance upvote, but what I miss here is *code indentation* (please, Mike, it's good for you and for us) and explicit definition of what are the relevant blocks of code, what does what? And what goes wrong?

Comment: @RustyToms I think I've written it out to be much more clear of what my intent is, hence giving it more or better relevance.

Comment: @b__ I'vr commented my code and added indentations so you can get a better feel for what I'm looking to execute here.

Comment: Define "Fixed navigation". I can guess, but might define it entirely different.

Comment: Cool. Giving the nav bar a position of "fixed" so it stick to the top and above everything.

Answer (score 0):

How about
http://jsfiddle.net/anaran/gYxK4/

No JS at all.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```
position: fixed;
```

leaves not space for such an element.

Therefor elements coming after it need to specify relative positioning and specify the relative position.

I added a white background which you might like or not.

```
.story {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    padding: 4%;
    top: 850px;
    left: 30px;
}
```